# how to split multiple parameter with newline with more than x parameter in swiftFormat

Tags: swift, xcode

is there any rule I can apply to format a newline when more than X number of parameter applied in function or list in swift? I am thinking more for the rule of [swift-style-guide](https://github.com/linkedin/swift-style-guide/blob/master/README.md) and I do not see any rule applied under [nicklockwood/SwiftFormat](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwiftFormat/blob/master/Rules.md)

```
1.10 When calling a function that has many parameters, put each argument on a separate line with a single extra indentation.
```

example

```
// before format
func abc(_ a: String, _ b: String, _ c:String) {

    try inside(_ aa: String, _ aa: String, _ aa: String, _ aa: String)
    // need new line here
}
// after format
func abc(_ a: String,
         _ b: String,
         _ c:String) {

    try inside(_ aa: String,
               _ bb: String,
               _ cc: String,
               _ dd: String)

    // need new line here
}
```

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of, but there is another rule: [***Choose parameter names to serve documentation.***](https://www.swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#parameter-names)

Comment: `Choose parameter names to serve documentation.`? how does this rule help?

Comment: AFAIK swiftformat doesnt support this, thats reason why I created this Xcode extension. I can modify it for you so you will have the braces as you want... 

https://apps.apple.com/app/muline/id6446231821

Answer (score 1):

In my company we put the first parameter on a new line so you don't get big leading whitespace areas:

```
func inside(
    aa: String,
    bb: String,
    cc: String,
    dd: String) throws {

    }

func abc(
    a: String,
    b: String,
    c: String) throws {
        try inside(
            aa: "",
            bb: "",
            cc: "",
            dd: "")
    }
```

(And as vadian suggests in his comment, you should avoid anonymous parameters. That is very un-Swifty. I refactored both your `abc()` and `inside()` functions to use named parameters.)

Consider a function with a longer name:

```
func hughJassFunctionName(aa: String,
                          bb: String,
                          cc: String,
                          dd: String) throws {
    //Your code
}
```

But if you put the first parameter on a new line, Swift's `Control-I` auto indentation formats it like this:

```
func hughJassFunctionName(
    aa: String,
    bb: String,
    cc: String,
    dd: String) throws {
        //Your code
    }
```